# Update form to database where the form was loaded in div using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have USER.PHP which load USERDETAIL.PHP inside

Inside USERDETAIL.PHP there is updateform (textfield's value is call from mysql)

When I press update button, nothing happened..

user.php

```
<html>
    <a href="#" onClick="permintaanAJAX('profil.php')">My Profile</a>
</html>
```

library.js

```
var objekXHR=false;
function permintaanAJAX(namaFile) {
    try {
        //  Firefox  IE7 etc
        objekXHR= new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (error) {
        try {
            //   IE 5 dan IE 6
            objekXHR = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (error) {
        return false;
    }
    }
    objekXHR.open("POST", namaFile);
    objekXHR.onreadystatechange = responAJAX;
    objekXHR.send(null);
}

function responAJAX() {
   if (objekXHR.readyState !=4) return;
   if (objekXHR.status==200) {
       // jika request sukses
       kaloSukses();
   } else alert("Request gagal: " + objekXHR.statusText);
   return true;
}
```

userdetail.php

```
<?php
include "session-s.php";
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
$koneksi_database = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$koneksi_database)
{
    die('Failed ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("fff", $koneksi_database);
$query_dari_db= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user where code_user='$username'");

if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $usql = "Update user set email='".$_POST['txtemail']."' where code_user='".$_POST['txtcode']."'";
    $updatedata = mysql_query($usql,$koneksi_database);

    print("<br><br><br> <font face = verdana size=2>You have updated your profile");
    echo message.alert("aa");
}
while($baris = mysql_fetch_array($query_dari_db))
{
?>
<form action="" method="post">  
    <table border="0">
        <tr>
            <td><img src=uploads/".$baris['attach']." width=100 height=100/>
            <td>
                <table border="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td>Kode User</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="txtkode" value="<?php echo $baris['code_user'];?>"  /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr><td>Nama</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="txtnama" value="<?php echo $baris['name'];?>"   /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr><td>Alamat</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="txtalamat" value="<?php echo $baris['adds'];?>"  /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr><td>No Telepon</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="txttelp" value="<?php echo $baris['phone'];?>"  /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr><td>Email</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="txtemail" value="<?php echo $baris['email'];?>"  /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr><td>Status</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="txtstatus" value="<?php echo $baris['status'];?>" disabled /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr><td>Attachment<td><input name="uploadedfile1" type="file" size=50 maxlength=50>
                    <tr><th colspan=2 align=right><td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></th>
                    </tr>
                </table>
    </table>
</form>

<?php
}
mysql_close($koneksi_database);
?>
```

Comment: You have SQL injection and XSS

Comment: @LawrenceCherone mean this code vulnerable to SQL Injection and XSS?

Comment: I could make a script to post `<script>alert('Some nice JS!');</script>` into the `$_POST['txtemail']` and then your directly outputting the values `$baris['email']` this is XSS.